# Skyrim Falling Death Loop

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Recently I was playing my level 55 character with 155 hours and I fell off of High Hrothgar. It autosaved 3 times while falling erasing any safe point I could back to and not lose 40+ hours and 5 levels.

How do I prevent my death while falling no starting point and just dying within 1 second of game loading?

I am wearing a full set of Nightingale Armor (Flawless) and some jewelry that helps with my magic (mage character) I'm a wood elf. I only have 2 elixirs of health and 1 health regeneration potion. Lots of ultimate healing potions. I want to continue this character without losing my 40 hours of gameplay.

I am on PS3, I have no Internet whatsoever. I do not need answers saying activate God Mode because I physically cant.

Comment: Do you have the [Become Ethereal](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Become_Ethereal) shout?

Comment: Do you really only have 1 second after the game loads before you die, or are you exaggerating?

Comment: I'm amazed someone managed to play 40+ hours of skyrim without saving manually, and yet it never crashed

Comment: I cannot use shouts when falling. Best I can do is use my potions but I still die. And yes I went 40+ hours without manually saving because I had autosave set to every 5 Minutes. Reason why game Autosaved 3 times while falling. Also literally one second https://youtu.be/oSXbV0aNC7Y

Comment: So you fell for 15+ minutes and didn't got bored watching your character fall?

Comment: I was trying to save her from falling and it autosaved everytime game would reload

Comment: Without mods or the console I'm not sure there's anything that you can do to avoid your new life as a pancake...

Comment: Wasn't there a speedrun strat where relogging would reset fall damage?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have the Become Ethereal shout, you're probably out of luck. You shouldn't be able to save while falling so your save should start with you on a solid platform and then falling - just try to shout before you fall.
Also, if you happen to have netch jelly from the Dawnguard DLC, consuming that will cause paralysis. When you fall while paralysed you'll bounce harmlessly off the ground regardless of height.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to save your character once it start falling off a cliff, as it is as the developers intended, unless you have enough damage reduction and the cliff isn't a mountain. Here listed are 2 possibles ways to reclaim your character from death:

1. If you own a driverless USB keyboard, try plugging it in. Once you've confirmed the playstation recognize it, see if you can open the console and type `tgm`. It is doubtful it is at all possible, but it is worth trying.
2. If the keyboard failed, you could try be to export your save file and load it with the computer's version of the game. I'm not sure if it is possible without jailbreaking the ps3.

Comment: Neither one of these answers will help. 1. That will fail because the console version probably has no commands integrated. 2. That will fail because the console version uses a different save format than the PC version.